# python how to read other_resources from exe file

Tags: python, windows, py2exe, portable-executable

I use `py2exe` like below and save some png files with `other_resources` in `PNG` table of the resulting exe file. all goes good and when inspecting the exe file I can see pngs are stored well there.

```
setup(
    ...
    windows     =[{
        'script'            : 'myscript.py',
        'icon_resources'    : [
            (0, 'favicon.ico'),

        ],
        'other_resources':[
            (1, 'PNG' , get_content('big_images_1.png')),
            (2, 'PNG' , get_content('big_images_2.png')),
        ]
)
```

Now I want to read them from the exe file. I search and find this code to read Icons

```
    icon_data    = win32api.LoadResource(0, win32con.RT_ICON, icon_id)
```

it also read bitmaps from exe but not userdefined PNG table.

can anyone help me to read them back from exe file?

thanks.

Comment: Is this project helpful? https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile

Answer (score 0):

I found it accidentally! By silly test for using `PNG` for resource_id!

```
png_data    = win32api.LoadResource(0, 'PNG', icon_id)
```